# Select multiple single cells in excel

Tags: excel, shortcut

Is there any way to select multiple single cells at once?

The rows are grouped as per the image below. So of course when I ctrl+arrow up it takes all the cells (including the ones hidden inside the group)

[image]

Is there a way to quickly (with a shortcut?) select single cells as per below?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at using `SUBTOTAL(109,...)` for summing the visible rows?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is better suited for https://superuser.com/.